# Power Automate Logic, Comparing Two Integers

Tags: excel-formula, powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-formula, power-automate-desktop

I'm working on a Power Automate Cloud Flow that sends an email reminders for users to reset their password.  I am having problems with the logic.

If

```
# Days Prior to Expire < 1st reminder in days
```

Then send email reminder

Excel table columns:
[image]

Power automate logic:
[image]

It is only supposed to email if the `# Days Prior to Expire < 1st reminder in days`

For the value of `31` for `# Days Prior to Expire`, it does not send an email as expected, due to it being less than `30` which is the value for `1st reminder in days`

All of the values in this column are > than `30`, so no emails should be sent for any.

However, it sends an email for all of the other values.

It seems like it is not making a good comparison, could it be due to the number of digits in the `# Days Prior to Expire` column?

The values in the columns are all integers.

I am expecting no email to be sent for any of these.

I've tried using an expression in the Power Automate condition, but instead have set all values to `int` in the excel table itself.

Comment: ensure the compare is being done on numeric values not string values.  Just becuase the values display as numeric doesn't mean their data type is.  So the > evaluation may be occuring as a string compare

Comment: So for the expressions something like `int(item('# Days Prior to Expire'))` for each?  Is that the correct syntax to reference the column value as I am in the screenshot?